# How can load j3o file by using three.js

Tags: three.js

J3O file is generated by JMonekyEngine, but I'm using three.js. for my project Is there anyway to load j3o file by using three.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in three.js to help you with that. 
So there are two options:

- use some tools provided by jMonkeyEngine to export the data into a format that works with other authoring-software (like blender) and export a format compatible with three.js from there (see here for a list of available loader-implementations: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/loaders, recommended formats would be glTF, Collada (.dae), Wavefront (.obj) - depending on what features you need.
- write the importer yourself and contribute it to three.js. This is probably very time-consuming, but as JME is open-source, it should be possible to get a pretty exact description of the file-format which you can parse and create three.js objects from.

Comment: ha, I saw you on the slack :)